# Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 Portable Forms need to "retouch" MainPAge.xaml to avoid errors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

sorry if this questions been asked already, I suspect it's quite common..

I'm using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 (4.0.3.214), and a common thing is that every now and again after saving or loading the project all the variables associated with the MainPage.xaml file are red, i.e. showing up as errors in the solution error list.

By retouching - saving the file after an edit (like adding a space then doing a backspace so nothing changes), the errors go away.

Which suggests a problem with the way Xamarin handles the build process and keeps track of auto-generated files. Is there a solution or a fix to this, or even a proper explanation ?

Comment: I'd probably post this as a bug on Xamarin's Bugzilla site...https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: XVS 4.1.0.111 does not exhibit that issue, but I am not sure when Community Edition get the beta/alpha Xamarin cycles that turn into a  stable release..

Comment: Note that instead of retouching the file you can right click any .xaml file in your solution and click on "Run custom tool" this will also regenerate the files and get rid of errors. You only do this once, it will regenerate all .xaml files. It's a bit easier, but of course, it's not a permanent solution.

Comment: @irreal thanks, that's a good tip..on the subject, has anyone experienced problems with intellisense with the community xamarin visual studio release ? It seems to stop working sometimes too

Comment: I have had major issues getting VS intellisense working in .xaml files. So I use ReSharper's XAML intellisense which works perfectly with Xamarin. I use VS intellisense for .cs and other files, no issues there.

Comment: @secretsquirrel, regarding Intellisense on XVS 4.0.x (and XS 5.10.x), yes we seen Intellisense appear to stop working for some users, never really figured it out for sure, after the bugs were worked out with Roslyn (as Xamarin switch from ICSharpCode.NRefactory to Roslyn for code analysis) we have not had any issues in regards to Intellisense